# Form Select value not being passed on submit [react

Tags: reactjs, django, forms, select

I am having troubles setting a **form select** within a react component:

when i submit the form all fields are filled out but the first select value (product) is not passed, while the second (transaction_type) is passed. My API is returning that that value cannot be null.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "product_id" of relation "product_transaction" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (33, 2022-02-22 18:30:22.458768+00, OUT, 2, aaa, null, null).
```

Please, what am i missing for it to grab that value and pass it on the submit?

```
function AddTransaction() {

    const [product, setTransactionProduct] = useState('1');
    const [transaction_type, setTransactionType] = useState('OUT');
    ...

    const [Products, setProducts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProducts = async () => {

        ...

        }
        fetchProducts()   
    }, [])

    const getProducts = () => {
        let list = [];

        Products.map(item => {
            return list.push(
                <option 
                    key={item.id} 
                    value={item.id}
                >
                    {item.title}
                </option>
            )
        })
        return list
    }
    
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const addToForm = async () => {

        let formfield = new FormData()

        formfield.append('product', product)
        formfield.append('transaction_type', transaction_type)
        ...

        await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction_create',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Authorization': '(*&^%$#@!)(*&^%$#*&^%@#$%^&*',
            },
            data: formfield,
           
            
        }).then((response) => {
            navigate(-1)
          }, (error) => {

          });
        
    }

    return ( 
            <div className='container'>
                <h5>Agregar transacci&oacute;n</h5>
                <form encType='multipart/form-data' >
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">Nombre del medicamento</label>
                        <select 
                            value={product}
                            className="form-control"                            
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                const selection = e.target.value;
                                setTransactionProduct(selection)
                                }
                            }
                        >
                            {getProducts()}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                        <label className="form-label">Entrada/Salida</label>
                        <select 
                            className="form-control"
                            value={transaction_type} 
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                    const selection = e.target.value;
                                    setTransactionType(selection)
                                }
                            }
                            >
                                <option  value='IN'>Entrada</option>
                                <option  value='OUT'>Salida</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    ...
                    
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={addToForm}>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        
    );
}

export default AddTransaction;
```

States are being updated accordingly, but value attr for select is not redered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but instead of `}).then((response) => {navigate(-1)`, consider `const addToForm = async e => { e.preventDefault()`. Maybe something's getting thrown off by the page reload.

Comment: i tried but still getting the same, thanks though. i noticed that the value attr of the select is not rendered

Comment: Can you add `console.log(formfield.get('product'))` before your `axios` call and let me know the result?

Comment: If placed before the axios call it prints the id of the product correctly, if placed within the error in the axios call, it returns "error 500", if placed after axios nothing gets printed.

Comment: Hmm, now that I look closer, seems the backend may be expecting `product_id`, but you are just passing it a key called `product`. Try changing this: `formfield.append('product', product)` to this: `formfield.append('product_id', product)`

Comment: Yeah, i guess that the serializer takes care of translating it to the appropiate field name. i tried though but still not working.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is actually a problem with the way you are processing the data on the backend. Would you like to add the code for the backend where you are doing that? Also, if you look at the Network tab on your browser developer tools, you can see the request that is being passed to the backend. That would be the final place to confirm what the frontend is actually sending!